# Is it permissible to take a supplement that contains an ingredient derived from pork?

Tags: halal-haram, medical, pork

Is it permissible to take a supplement that contains an ingredient derived from pork?  Even if it’s needed as part of a treatment process?

I want to take an HCL and digestive enzymes supplement that contain pepsin. From what I read, pepsin is needed to restore HCL acid in the stomach but it's derived from a pig's liver. It helps with digesting protein, what does Islam say about that?

I originally used the supplement without knowing that pepsin was derived from a pig. I was able to eat eggs and anything without getting stomach ache and brain fog. After I found out it comes from pig, I stopped the supplement and found one that is derived from plants. The only problem is that I don't feel as good as the animal based enzymes. I still get brain fog and its preventing me from studying and this is my last semester in school. I honestly doesn't know what to do now. I can try other supplements but it would take time and money and I don't have both.

Is it halal to continue with a supplement that contains pepsin from a pig until I heal my stomach or is it haram?

Answer (score -2):

As you probably know, there are some verses in the holy Quran which declare that pig (pork) is haram… , such as 2:173 or 5:3 and so on. As a rule of Allah, we probably are aware that there must be some disadvantages in the matters which are named as haram matters such as pork. Then we should observe it since it could be profitable for us avoiding eating it in any way. Of course there seem it could be permissible in some specific emergency situations. So emergency situation is limited in really emergency limited situations, not every situations.

Consequently you ought to pay attention that does your situation really considered as an emergency situation or not. Besides, as another significant point, you’d better notice that using pork could make many diseases (mental, physical), and many viruses such as  Nipah, Sars or several bactorias like Salmonellosis, Listeria and even Coli Balantidum, Trichinella spiralis,.. (as well as disagreeing against the order of Allah). Hence according to your explanation it seems that it doesn’t be considered as a vital emergency situation to be a permission… since as a general rule, you’d get many other diseases in lieu of …!

And Allah knows best.

---

**Reference:**

- [http://tanzil.net/](https://tanzil.net/#24:31)

Answer (score -2):

Consuming pork is haram. Even for an atheist to eat pork, he must heat it up so hot the bonds between the fat cells break down into grease (140 degrees), but not so hot it turns to ash. You're taking a chance the pork was processed correctly to remove the parasites. An atheist says "Be very careful eating pork products." But Allah recommends the fish.